# Python: How to pass different arguments in lambda function when creating Tkinter buttons in a loop?

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is my script currently:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Soundboard(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, sounds, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.sounds = sounds

        self.pack()    
        self.create_button_loop()

    def create_button_loop(self):
        self.buttons = {}
        for name, sound in self.sounds.items():
            self.buttons[name] = tk.Button(self, text=name, command = lambda :play_sound(sound))
            self.buttons[name].pack(side='top')    
        #sound = 10



def play_sound(a_sound):
    print(a_sound)


#MAIN SCRIPT
if __name__ == '__main__':

    sounds = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
    board = Soundboard(sounds)
```

There is one class, `Soundboard`, and one function, `play_sound`, and the script section at the bottom. Sounds is a dict with the pattern `{name : sound}` Currently `sound` is just a number, and the function `play_sound` just prints what is called to it.

The problem I've been having is in the `create_button_loop` method of `Soundboard`. In the loop, for each `name`/`sound` combination, a button is created in the dict `self.buttons` where `name` is the button's text and `sound` is passed to `play_sound` (the lambda statement).

What I want to happen is for the `sound` passed through the lambda statement to be `sound` when the button is created, not what `sound` is when the button is pressed, so `play_sound` should print the original value of `sound`. What actually happens is that as `sound` gets reassigned later (by the next iteration of the loop), when the button is pressed `play_sound` plays whatever the current value of `sound` is.

In this example, 3  buttons are created, "a" "b" and "c". When "a" is pressed, "3" is printed (most recent reassignment of `sound` is in the last iteration of the for loop, so `name`/`sound` = `c`/`3` instead of "1", as it was when button "a" was created.

How can I avoid the `sound` value being passed in the lambda statement changing when `sound` changes? I'd much prefer some iterated method like this as opposed to writing a different callback function for each `{name:sound}` combination, but if that is the best way then let me know. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `functools.partial` instead of lambda.

```
from functools import partial
...
self.buttons[name] = tk.Button(self, text=name, command=partial(play_sound, sound))
```